# Serialization of enum fields in Java

Tags: java, serialization, enums

From the [Javadoc of ObjectInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html):

> Enum constants are deserialized differently than ordinary serializable
>   or externalizable objects. The serialized form of an enum constant
>   consists solely of its name; field values of the constant are not
>   transmitted. To deserialize an enum constant, ObjectInputStream reads
>   the constant name from the stream; the deserialized constant is then
>   obtained by calling the static method Enum.valueOf(Class, String) with
>   the enum constant's base type and the received constant name as
>   arguments. Like other serializable or externalizable objects, enum
>   constants can function as the targets of back references appearing
>   subsequently in the serialization stream. The process by which enum
>   constants are deserialized cannot be customized: any class-specific
>   readObject, readObjectNoData, and readResolve methods defined by enum
>   types are ignored during deserialization. Similarly, any
>   serialPersistentFields or serialVersionUID field declarations are also
>   ignored--all enum types have a fixed serialVersionUID of 0L.

Why are enums in Java not serialized on their entirety? Enums in Java are more than mere constants and are full fledged classes that can also contain state. Does it not result in inconsistent state between the sending and the receiving ends? What is that fundamental point that I am missing here?

Comment: *Enums in Java are full fledged classes that can contain state also?* A Java `enum` can contain state and depending how you design it you can change its state, note that, of course, changing the state of an `enum` is not a good practice.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The lesson is to not use enums when you need mutable objects. Yes, you can design enums that maintain an internal state, but they weren't designed for that. As in the case of serialization, not all parts of Java will cooperate if you do.

If you must tie `enum` values to state data, use an [`EnumMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/EnumMap.html). That class implements `Serializable`, so you won't need to do any additional work to serialize your state data (provided the state data objects are themselves serializable).