# Serialize an object with enum member in Java?

Tags: java, serialization, enums

If I have a class and enum as follows:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
public enum Color {
    RED,
    BLUE
}
public class Person implements Serializable {
    String name;
    int age;
    Color favColor;
}
```

Assuming that I construct it and set all members to a value, will this correctly serialize and de-serialize? If not, how can I alter `enum Color` to allow serialization?

Comment: Similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18361190/serialization-of-enum-fields-in-java

Comment: Here's the declaration of `java.lang.Enum`: `public abstract class Enum<E extends Enum<E>> implements Comparable<E>, Serializable`. That should answer your question.

Comment: Yes it will. What happened when you tried it?

Answer (score 1):

Which serialization library are you using?

If you are using Jackson, the following line:

```
new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(Color.RED);
```

should yield the String "RED".

GSON does the same - serializes and deserializes by using the name of the enum instead of the ordinal value:

```
System.out.println(gson.toJson(Color.RED));
```

should print

```
 {"Color": "RED"}
```